# Script injection and making an ajax call before returning result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xss

Attempting something a bit complicated and I hope it is possible, or someone might suggest a way to do it.

On site A I have a database with booking information.

On site B I want to show people when these bookings are taking place.

So on site A I create a php page which takes all of that data and puts it into JSON.

I then create a js script to run an ajax call to that php page, return the information and use javascript to create a table and build it wherever the script was called.

Kind of like twitter's widget.

Now what I want to do, is have a couple of lines of code pasted into site B, which calls the js script on site A, which runs the ajax command, then gets the data, creates the table I mentioned and puts it on site B.

Is that possible? Will the script make the ajax call on site A before passing it to site B? Or will it not be able to do the ajax call because it is put on site B first and I can't call to site A from site B?

Comment: what sort "lines of code" do you want to be pasted? could you not just add a js file to site B that just does the ajax call?

Comment: Not really, it's going to be different for every site.

Basically it takes the user's unique identification code, and sends it to the original script.

That script then makes the ajax call, gets the details and sends it back. Kind of like twitter's widget feature. It'll be different for many other sites, so it wouldn't be good to have the many sites linking in paste a whole string of code. Rather than one line which can easily be tinkered with on site A, so as to limit potential problems on each individual site.

Comment: Sorry the lines of code.

It's booking information, so it'll create a widget including rooms, and dates that are available (but removing dates that aren't available and capacities essentially) which will be different for each unique idea. So that is why I want to do it in such a specific manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible but the way is a bit different from you suggested.

Firstly to answer your questions: When you include that "data fetcher" script from site A on site B, it will be executed on Site B. It will try to perform ajax call to site A and will fail because of same-origin policy.

The way to accomplish this is via [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

You need to first create a php page, which produces some json data and calls a predefined javascript function like:

**fetcher.php:**

```
<?php
$data = fetchCustomerBookings($_GET['customerid']);
echo "renderBookings(".json_encode($data).")";
?>
```

Then you can include this script on Site B with an ordinary script tag like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://site-a.com/fetcher.php?customerid=XXX"></script>
```

There you need to have defined renderBookings javascript function already.

Comment: Thank you very much :) that makes a lot of sense! I appreciate the response and will try it out